# how to reflect changes made on postgres database of django from one pc to other

Tags: django, postgresql

We three working with Django and postgres is the database. Whenever we push the code to GitHub. The database data is not reflecting. The data I stored is visible to me only. The postgres user, password and database name are same on all our laptops. How to make when I push that has to go their databases also.

Comment: your postgresql database should be on server instead of local machines to reflect data on each laptop. where is you postgresql runnning?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about changes in db schema, then take a look django migrations - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/. The workflow is following:

- change model (e.g. add new field, change existing field...)
- generate migration  file by running `python manage.py makemigrations`. This generates migration file in `<app_folder>/migrations`
- Run `python manage.py migrate` to apply changes in models to your database
- Add migration file to your version control (github or whaever) and push it

Now when your colleagues gets updated code from version control they need to run `python manage.py migrate` to apply model changes to their local database.

Comment: not the changes in models which are reflecting well. But needed data entered into it.

Comment: If you want the same data, then you probably should use the same database server (running in network that you all can access). Or exchange dump files with data (pg_dump / pg_restore). Or, if you are talking about some initial data for models, then django fixtures might be helpful - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is not possible to send postgress data directly. But sqlite can be used for it. This link aids in that - https://manuelvanrijn.nl/blog/2012/01/18/convert-postgresql-to-sqlite/ . But i send data by taking backup like
From Postgres to Postgres: taking backup :
pg_dump dbname > dbname.bak
and then on new Postgres restored  with:
psql test < dbname.bak